# OnPropertyChanged() vs PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Consider this example. In my viewmodel I have two properties, `Image` and `HasImage`. Obviously, `HasImage` is depedent on `Image` and should be updated whenever `Image` is updated. This can be done in at least two ways, as shown below.

**Considering both performance and design, which method is the best?**

---

### Solution 1

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}

private void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Image")
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(() => HasImage);
    }
}

public bool HasImage
{
    get
    {
        return (Image != null);
    }
}

public BitmapSource Image
{
    get
    {
        return this.image;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.image != value)
        {
            this.image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Image);
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

```
public MyViewModel()
{
}

public bool HasImage
{
    get
    {
        return (Image != null);
    }
}

public BitmapSource Image
{
    get
    {
        return this.image;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.image != value)
        {
            this.image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Image);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => HasImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance has to be better with the second because you are not registering an event handler, nor are you invoking that extra method.

As far as design, I see the second more often and it is what prefer.

However, in reality, just use something like [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) and let it take care of it for you.  As a note, it will do the second.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks. Will look at Fody!